# How can I use the client side of soap in my spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, dependency-injection

I'm working on a project right now and I want to use SOAP web service with dependency injection in my Spring Boot project, but I'm having a problem.

As you can see below, I'm injecting using `@Autowired` annotation, but it shows this problem:

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'KNIKPSPublicSoap' type found.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JobSeekerManager implements JobSeekerService {

    private final JobSeekerDal jobSeekerDal;

    @Autowired
    private KNIKPSPublicSoap soapClientWS; 


    @Override
    public void save(JobSeeker jobSeeker) {
        //logica

        this.jobSeekerDal.save(jobSeeker);
    }

    @Override
    public List<JobSeeker> findAll() {
        return this.jobSeekerDal.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Do you have a `KNIKPSPublicSoap` bean declared somewhere? Only after you declare the bean can you inject it some place else

Comment: @Bogdan I did not declare it anywhere. I just declared from the packaged class as ready. So where can I declare it?

Comment: In order to autowire a bean, that bean must be declared either in an XML Spring application context or be annotated with discoverable annotations so that Spring can find them and load them in the context, such as `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository`, etc. Is `KNIKPSPublicSoap` declared as a bean in XML configuration or annotated as a component in a scanable package by Spring?